# Is there a better way of exporting multiple named functions in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a better way of writing the below lines?

```
const TFieldUi = withTranslation()(FieldUi);
const TDisplayFieldUi = withTranslation()(DisplayFieldUi);

export {
  TFieldUi as FieldUi,
  TDisplayFieldUi as DisplayFieldUi,
};
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with those lines. What is bothering you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the keyword [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) in front of each variable

```
export const FieldUi = (props) => {}
```

`default` keyword works as well, only one per file obviously.

```
export default const FieldUi = (props) => {}
```